# web api can't read claims on request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm using WebApi 2.0 with Identity 2.0

I have ApplicationCookie authentication defined in startup.auth.cs like this :

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieName = "MyAppCookieName"
        });

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
```

I have action in AccountController to login :

```
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        // create required claims
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "harryb"));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "harryb"));

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        }, identity);

        return Ok();
```

So far so good , cookie was received in client on login request. But when i make new request , claims are empty ? I don't want to use standart login and tables and etc.. i just want to some claims on fake login and read it in next request .. What i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly found what's going wrong 
..
From [Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login in ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)

Find this :

> In particular, the MVC portion of your app might use forms
> authentication, which stores credentials in a cookie. Cookie-based
> authentication requires the use of anti-forgery tokens, to prevent
> CSRF attacks. That’s a problem for web APIs, because there is no
> convenient way for the web API to send the anti-forgery token to the
> client. (For more background on this issue, see Preventing CSRF
> Attacks in Web API.) Calling SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication ensures
> that Web API is not vulnerable to CSRF attacks from credentials stored
> in cookies.

So in WebApiConfig find this
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
//config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();

which creates a problem for me .. In other word you can't use cookie authentication in WebApi securly ..